# Cannot start emacs server

Tags: server

I'm running Debian Jessie. I have installed emacs24-lucid package. I tried running emacs --daemon and got this:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50festival.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50festival.el (source)...done

Backtrace:
emacs[0x8130d29]
emacs[0x81189e6]
emacs[0x812fb9e]
emacs[0x812fc0b]
linux-gate.so.1(__kernel_sigreturn+0x0)[0xb775ed1c]
emacs[0x8194292]
emacs[0x819abac]
emacs[0x819b36d]
emacs[0x80ed071]
emacs[0x80ec057]
emacs[0x81857d0]
emacs[0x81b893d]
emacs[0x8185317]
emacs[0x8186873]
emacs[0x8184b09]
emacs[0x81a718b]
emacs[0x81a7867]
emacs[0x81857a7]
emacs[0x81b893d]
emacs[0x8185317]
emacs[0x818565b]
emacs[0x8185a03]
emacs[0x81a7fa5]
emacs[0x81857a7]
emacs[0x81b893d]
emacs[0x8185391]
emacs[0x818565b]
emacs[0x81b893d]
emacs[0x8185391]
emacs[0x818565b]
emacs[0x8184e11]
emacs[0x818793b]
emacs[0x81b9963]
emacs[0x8185391]
emacs[0x818565b]
emacs[0x81b893d]
emacs[0x8185391]
emacs[0x8186873]
emacs[0x8184b09]
emacs[0x8186f67]
emacs[0x8118ef4]
...
Error: server did not start correctly
```

Not sure what could be causing this. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I can start server from within emacs. As a workaround, I am using an emacs instance as the "server".

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.  Upgrade to Emacs-25 to see if we fixed it already, and if not please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

I use 32-bit `emacs24-lucid` on `jessie` with `--daemon`, its working fine.

Try running `emacs -Q --daemon` to see if there is a package in jessie installed, which causes the problems. If this is working you might to deinstall a debian package or disable the emacs-start-code. If running with `-Q` is not working then this answer will not help you.

Emacs-extensions installed as debian packages store their startup code in `/etc/emacs/site-lisp/` or `/etc/emacs24/site-lisp/`. Also have a look at `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/`. You can temporary rename/remove those files to find the package which causes this problem.

Comment: Elisp should never crash Emacs. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bug-Criteria.html.